# Array sort and print reversed

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to sort my array in the same as I did it here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[3];

    System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
    numbers[0] = sc.nextInt();
    numbers[1] = sc.nextInt();
    numbers[2] = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println("After: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

}
```

My problem is, that it should now be reversed. So it shoudln't be ascending but downwards. Can anybody help me?

Comment: you need the array sorted and reversed, or sorted and _just_ printed in reverse as per your question title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change from `int[]` to `Integer[]`, then you can use overloaded version of [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29), and pass a `Comparator` returned by [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29) as second argument:

```
Arrays.sort(numbers, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Note that **this will not work with `int[]`** primitive array.

Comment: ^ Good point made here, you'll have to change int[] to Integer[] but it won't make a difference to the contents of your array.

Comment: @FaresA. What do you mean by that last part of your comment?

Comment: int[] and Integer[] won't make a difference to his program.

Comment: @FaresA. Overloaded `Arrays.sort()` won't work with primitive arrays.

Comment: I meant for everything besides that, it won't affect the rest of the program.

Answer (score 6):

`Arrays.sort(numbers,Collections.reverseOrder());`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) library, which has really useful methods including `.reverseOrder()`. It basically works like this:

`Integer[] yourReversedArray = Arrays.sort(yourArrayHere, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` does in-place sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reverse you sorted array :

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length / 2; i++) 
{
    int temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[numbers.length - i - 1];
    numbers[numbers.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

or with apache  Commons.Lang (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) :

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array)
```